# How i can send a message to a specific device with identifierForVendor or openUDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I'm writing an app that manage accounts stored in a server,like any other social app. What i wanna do is to forbid a double login with the same account in two devices. So when a user will log to my app i have to log out any other devices that is logged with the same credentials. To identify the device i use openUDID for ios<6 and identifierForVendor for ios>=6. The devices id are stored in the server db. There's a way to take this id and send a notification/messagge to the related device? I know that i can simply check the actual device id and the stored id to know if is the same device...it's not enough, i need to send a notification to the device. How i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to send a message to an other device is through APNS.

Take a look at this tutorial -> h[ttp://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2)